# Starting an Android Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, background-service

Sorry if this is a dumb question but how do initiate an android service? I cant figure out the error code on `public class scilentservice extends IntentService {` (see code below). I think it might have something to do with the intent but i'm not positive. What I want is for my app to start the service which would then auto science the phone at certain times.
Here is my code

```
/**
 * Created by Abe on 3/29/2015.
 */

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class scilentservice extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
        ...
        // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString
        ...
    }
}
`
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "Auto science the phone at certain times" ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: "_I cant figure out the error code_" What error code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will get downvoted and possibly closed because it's basic information found with a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=android+Intent%20Service). Please look at the documentation linked in the comments and then the [next step](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html) on how to send a request… this is the Android documentation.

Snippet:

Create a new, explicit Intent for the IntentService called RSSPullService.

```
/*
 * Creates a new Intent to start the RSSPullService
 * IntentService. Passes a URI in the
 * Intent's "data" field.
 */
mServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RSSPullService.class);
mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(dataUrl));
```

Call startService()

```
// Starts the IntentService
getActivity().startService(mServiceIntent);
```

The intentService code:

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {

    public RSSPullService() {
        super("RSSPullService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Do the work here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `extends Intent` instead and override the method `onStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    return 1;
}
```

And you either start the service on some command sent from an activity or some notification sent to the application.

Comment: That's not the same thing. An IntentService shouldn't override onStartCommand because that gets called by the base class.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Thats why I said I used a Service instead and it has worked

Comment: Which is worse, because a `Service` is not the same thing as an `IntentService`, yes. If you use a service you have to override onStartCommand. But the user is not asking to use a Service as far as I can understand from his question.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini The question says how to initiate an android service and thought this might help.

Comment: You're right. I think this is a case of "The User Has No Clue". In any case, no further information was provided so I doubt there's much else to do here.